# Match Regular expression from a dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, regex, dictionary, match

I am trying to have some sort of Data Object (I'm thinking a dictionary) to hold a TON of regular expressions as keys, then I need to take a string of text, and match against them to get the actual value from the Dictionary. I need an efficient way to do this for a large set of data.

I am in C# and I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: Based on the answers so far, you might want to provide more detail in your question about your particular application.

Comment: Roughly how many expressions are in a ton? How large is the text they will be matching? How frequently will new text be provided? How quickly do results need to be returned?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not use LINQ?

```
Dictionary<string, string> myCollection = new Dictionary<string, string>();

myCollection.Add("(.*)orange(.*)", "Oranges are a fruit.");
myCollection.Add("(.*)apple(.*)", "Apples have pips.");
myCollection.Add("(.*)dog(.*)", "Dogs are mammals.");
// ...

string input = "tell me about apples and oranges";

var results = from result in myCollection
              where Regex.Match(input, result.Key, RegexOptions.Singleline).Success
              select result;

foreach (var result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.Value);
}

// OUTPUT:
//
// Oranges are a fruit.
// Apples have pips.
```

Comment: I am going to start with this solution, so far its running pretty fast with a dictionary of about 500 items. If it gets worse, I will look into other alternatives. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remember that if you are planning on using a regex more than once you can create a regex object as compiled and re-use it to reduce overhead.

```
Regex RegexObject = new Regex(Pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Using this model you would be best storing a regex object rather than the pattern string.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you actually need regular expressions for this - you could use a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Representing dictionaries is a common application for a trie. (I'm assuming you mean a dictionary as in a list of words, and not the "associative array" meaning).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean match a string against the regexes to get a regex match? Or just a text match? In other words, is the string you have going to BE one of those regexes, or some data to APPLY a regex to?

If it IS a regex and you want to find it in the list, you don't need a Dictionary, those are 2 part containers. You could just use a List or StringCollection, and ask for IndexOf(mytString), -1 meaning it's not in there.

Answer (score 0):

If your regexps aren't trivial single-strings, and you care for efficiency, you'd want to represent them in a single [NFA (nondeterministic finite-state automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_state_machine), with values in final states.  If it's possible for an input to match more than one regexp, then final states would need a set of values.

At this point, you're prepared to consider optimizing the automaton.  If it can be practically determinized (this give you a DFA that can be exponentially larger than the NFA), then by all means do that.  Once you have a DFA, you can efficiently (and uniquely up to isomorphism) minimize it (but since you have values in your final states, an obvious modification of the [usual algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dfa_minimization) is needed).

There are also techniques for minimizing NFA directly.  For example, if two states have the same suffix sets ({(rest of string,value)}) they're equivalent and can be combined.  Equivalence in an acyclic NFA can be done via [hash-consing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_consing) starting from the final states.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `RegexPatternDictionaryImpl` type in the following repo which can be used for the purpose of storing Regexes as keys and whatever you want as values. This dictionary isn't optimized for performance though. It just does a linear scan of the keys and matches them to a given string to return all matching values. However, for small use-cases this dictionary will suffice:

https://github.com/ColmBhandal/CsharpExtras/blob/master/CsharpExtras/Dictionary/RegexPatternDictionaryImpl.cs

The dictionary is relatively stable, with a number of tests written here:

https://github.com/ColmBhandal/CsharpExtras/blob/master/CsharpExtrasTest/Dictionary/RegexPatternDictionaryTest.cs

If you want to code it yourself, here's a snapshot of the source code as of the time of writing this answer. Note: you may have to disentangle certain aspects of the library to get this working:

```
namespace CsharpExtras.Dictionary
{
    public class RegexPatternDictionaryImpl<TValue> : 
      IRegexPatternDictionary<TValue>
    {
    private readonly IDictionary<string, TValue> _baseDictionary;
    private readonly IDictionary<Regex, string> _regexDictionary;

    public RegexPatternDictionaryImpl()
    {
        _baseDictionary = new Dictionary<string, TValue>();
        _regexDictionary = new Dictionary<Regex, string>();
    }

    public void Add(string pattern, TValue value)
    {
        AddRegexToDictionary(pattern, pattern, value);
    }

    public ICollection<TValue> FindAllValuesThatMatch(string textKey)
    {
        ICollection<TValue> result = new List<TValue>();
        foreach (var item in _regexDictionary.Where(r => r.Key.IsMatch(textKey)))
        {
            result.Add(_baseDictionary[item.Value.ToString()]);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public bool HasMatch(string textKey)
    {
        return _regexDictionary.Any(r => r.Key.IsMatch(textKey));
    }

    public ICollection<(string pattern, TValue values)> FindAllPatternValuePairsThatMatch(string textKey)
    {
        ICollection<(string pattern, TValue values)> result = new List<(string pattern, TValue values)>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<Regex, string> item in _regexDictionary.Where(r => r.Key.IsMatch(textKey)))
        {
            result.Add((item.Key.ToString(), _baseDictionary[item.Value.ToString()]));
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void AddEscapedFullMatchPattern(string pattern, TValue value)
    {
        string escapedPattern = Regex.Escape(pattern);
        string fullMatchPattern = MakePatternMatchFullString(escapedPattern);
        AddRegexToDictionary(fullMatchPattern, pattern, value);
    }

    public void AddFullMatchPattern(string pattern, TValue value)
    {
        string fullMatchPattern = MakePatternMatchFullString(pattern);
        AddRegexToDictionary(fullMatchPattern, pattern, value);
    }

    #region Base dictionary methods
    public TValue this[string key] { get => _baseDictionary[key]; set => _baseDictionary[key] = value; }

    public ICollection<string> Keys => _baseDictionary.Keys;

    public ICollection<TValue> Values => _baseDictionary.Values;

    public int Count => _baseDictionary.Count;

    public bool IsReadOnly => _baseDictionary.IsReadOnly;

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<string, TValue> item)
    {
        _baseDictionary.Add(item);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _baseDictionary.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<string, TValue> item)
    {
        return _baseDictionary.Contains(item);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(string key)
    {
        return _baseDictionary.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<string, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _baseDictionary.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _baseDictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool Remove(string key)
    {
        return _baseDictionary.Remove(key);
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<string, TValue> item)
    {
        return _baseDictionary.Remove(item);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(string key, out TValue value)
    {
        return _baseDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _baseDictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }
    #endregion

    private void AddRegexToDictionary(string actualPattern, string keyPattern, TValue value)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(actualPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled);
        _baseDictionary.Add(keyPattern, value);
        _regexDictionary.Add(regex, keyPattern);
    }

    private string MakePatternMatchFullString(string pattern)
    {
        string updatedPattern = pattern;
        if (!pattern.StartsWith("^"))
        {
            updatedPattern = "^" + updatedPattern;
        }
        if (!pattern.EndsWith("$"))
        {
            updatedPattern += "$";
        }
        return updatedPattern;
    }
}
```

}

## Disclosure

The above repo is maintained by me on my personal GitHub website.

Comment: When you link to your own resources, you need to be explicit about it. See [How not to be a spammer.](/help/promotion)

Comment: Good point @tripleee I should really be including code snippets first off and then linking to the open source library afterwards.

Comment: And I should also be explicit that those links above are my own repo. Will fix the answer now.

Comment: However, this answer absolutely is not spam and validly answers the question of the OP.